# How to host ASP.NET Core under IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

At the moment `ASP.NET Core` doesn't save proper values in `web.config` to bind site to `IIS`, see this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"

stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" 

forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
```

This variable are set only on publish. But I prefer to debug my site using following URLs:

- http://localhost/zerosite-admin
- http://localhost/zerosite-api

Is it possible?

Any best practices of how you develop are welcome!

Comment: Are you talking about environment variables or arguments in aspNetCore tag inside web.config ?

Comment: We had the same problem, and we simply ended up using `IIS Express` and `http://localhost:<port>` URLs for all `.NET Core` web apps.
However, if you don't use `OAuth` and/or `HTTPS`, maybe it would suffice to run projects as Console apps and don't use `IIS`.

Comment: ok, thanks. It's sad.